# Ansible not evaluating correctly mutiple ansible_facts.packages

Tags: ansible

I have strange issue, I'm sure its just something trivial but I'm stuck.

ansible 2.9.21

I have tasks that should not run if any of 3 or 4 packages are not present on the target.

So at the play beginning I do run:

```yaml
- name: Gather the package facts
  package_facts:
    manager: auto
```

Which givers me ansible_facts.packages with all the packages on the server

Next there is some example task:

```yaml
- name: "Copying temporary files"
  copy:
    src: files.zip
    dest: /tmp/files.zip
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
  when:
    - inventory_hostname in groups['cluster_nodes']
    - "'pcs' not in ansible_facts.packages"
    - "'fence-agents-mpath' not in ansible_facts.packages"
    - "'pacemaker' not in ansible_facts.packages"
```

Now on purpose I remove `fence-agents-mpath` from server and expected behaviours would be that the task runs because one of the conditions is not met. Thinking about it now, AND operator would not be the right choice probably, but using OR also is not evaluated correctly:

```yaml
when:
  - inventory_hostname in groups['cluster_nodes']
  - ( "'pcs' not in ansible_facts.packages" ) or ( "'pacemaker' not in ansible_facts.packages" ) or ( "'fence-agents-mpath' not in ansible_facts.packages" )
```

With that it rest executed on servers where all 3 packages are present... I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

This is because:

> You can use [logical operators](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#logic) to combine conditions. When you have multiple conditions that all need to be true (that is, a logical `and`), you can specify them as a list

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-ansible-facts*</sup>

So by doing

```yaml
when:
  - inventory_hostname in groups['cluster_nodes']
  - "'pcs' not in ansible_facts.packages"
  - "'fence-agents-mpath' not in ansible_facts.packages"
  - "'pacemaker' not in ansible_facts.packages"
```

You are basically saying:

```
When pcs AND fence-agents-mpath AND pacemaker are not installed
```

What you need here is an `or`:

```yaml
when:
  - inventory_hostname in groups['cluster_nodes']
  - "'pcs' not in ansible_facts.packages" or "'fence-agents-mpath' not in ansible_facts.packages" or "'pacemaker' not in ansible_facts.packages"
```

---

Also in your current or statement you left out some negations

```
( "'pcs' not in ansible_facts.packages" ) or 
( "'pacemaker' in ansible_facts.packages" ) or 
##             ^--- missing negation here
( "'fence-agents-mpath' in ansible_facts.packages" )
##                      ^--- another missing negation here
```

Comment: using OR is also not seems to be correct. than it will get run on nodes where it is installed also. I don't know why is this happening, since OR is the logical way. ( Yes I missed "not in" fixed that )

Comment: shorter and more flexible way to write the condition: 1) put your pkgs in a list var `check_package: ['pcs', 'pacemaker', 'fence-agents-mpath']` 2) then check at least one package is not there`ansible_facts.packages | intersect(check_package) | length < check_package | length`.

Comment: @Zeitounator thanks a ton ! this solution is working correclty

Comment: Yet an other way: `check_package | difference(ansible_facts.packages | intersect(check_package)) | length > 0`